# Right Mysql collation for â î û

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, collation

```
$str = 'elhamdûlillahî rabbil âlemin';
```

I am sending something like this. It does not appear correctly. I 've tried many things.

Or should i do something in my PHP page? How can i understand what collation style my PHP page using? and how to change it? Thanks.

Comment: Declaring it as UTF-8 in your meta tags will probably solve your problem. But if you are going to store strings like this in a MySQL database, for instance, then maybe you have to do some magic to it.

Comment: **Collation** is used for performing string *comparisons*.  You have not mentioned that you're performing a comparison, nor (if you are) what (if anything) is wrong with that comparison.  Therefore I don't think you actually meant to discuss "collation" in your question.  **Encoding**, on the other hand, is a means of representing text inside a computer—and if the software you use expects a different encoding to that actually used, you'll encounter problems of the sort you describe.  So you likely have an "encoding" issue.  See [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170).

Comment: @EddeAlmeida its not about html. pure PHP sends the string. So meta tag is not the solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: @FirstOne yes it did the magic. All i need was `$mysqli->set_charset('utf8')` in my PHP page.

Comment: "Does not appear correctly?"  `Ã¢ Ã® Ã»` (Mojibake)?  Question mark(s)?  Truncation?  `� � �`?